# DirectX application doesn't render on laptop

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

**UPDATE 1:**
I have tried the c++ source for the same tutorial and that ran fine on the laptop.

**UPDATE 2:**
I bit the bullet and decided to work on the project in c++ instead. So far everything that was in the C# version works fine in the c++ version. I could not work out or resolve my issue.

I'm developing a small DirectX project using the SharpDX wrapper. I am using VS2015 Community edition and I am also running Windows 10. I have been following the tutorials on (see reply comments #1) and, in particular, the C# conversions of the tutorials found here (see reply comments #2). I don't have 10 rep so I can only post 2 links....

I have followed the tutorials to generate terrain as shown below. This is rendered from my desktop PC.

[image]

But when I copy the project over to my laptop, the application does not render the terrain and I am left with a blank screen

[image]

I have tried swapping the driver type to reference for the laptop but it still won't render. On occasions the application will run (but not render) without crashing on the laptop but sometimes it will crash just after starting or when the window is closed (majority when the window is closed).

The error is: Unhandled exception at 0x770A5C0C (ntdll.dll) in pEngine.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters 0x770D6478)

followed by: wntdll.pdb not loaded.

And then no further information. I have tried reinstalling VS but that didn't change anything. I have tried creating a new project on the laptop and importing the code but that also didn't change anything (suggests not a code problem?). I also gave the project to a friend who tested it on their desktop (it worked and rendered) and then they tested it on their laptop and it didn't work with the same error.

I have tried running the **terrain** tutorial samples and they also do not run on the laptop which suggests there is nothing wrong with the code. I have also tested all of the other tutorials (non-terrain tutorials) and they work fine on the laptop.

So I'm wondering if this is a hardware issue due to the laptop?

In my render loop after the begin scene call, I render the terrain and apply the colorshader to show the grid effect

```
D3D.BeginScene( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
......
terrain.Render( D3D.deviceContext );

if( !colorShader.Render( D3D.deviceContext, terrain.indexCount, worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix ) )
{
    return false;
}
```

If I comment out the colorshader.render call, the application stops crashing on the laptop. From there it seems to be an issue with the ColorShader.cs class which can be viewed from the rastertek codeplex link. (I don't want to make this any longer for now, but I'll happily post my code if requested)

I'm thinking it's a hardware/laptop issue or a possible shader issue that I'm not addressing but I'm new to this so I'm not really sure. (the debug help isn't telling me anything either).

Comment: http://www.rastertek.com/
https://rastertekdx.codeplex.com/

Comment: Your program crashes in kernel, so it is most likely you are feeding native DirectX implementation of SharpDX with something wrong. Maybe it's just a corrupted array or some size you pass is bigger than expected (like number of vertices or indices). There are zillion things can go wrong with DirectX program. Different drivers and hardware platforms behave differently when undefined behavior is triggered by heap corruption. On desktops you most likely use Nvidia or AMD dedicated GPU, on laptop it is likely an Intel integrated graphics. That's why your results are inconsistent between platforms.

Comment: So are you saying there may be an issue with the code but the desktop drivers/hardware don't care about it and run anyway? I've sort-of came into this assuming that it will work on any windows device but I should really be considering different hardware/drivers?

Comment: Most of the time you just write code that does not trigger undefined behavior, it will be guaranteed to work everywhere. You only care about underlying hardware and driver infrastructure when you are choosing target feature level or if you are an expert and optimizing for performance or quality.

Comment: I see. So is there a way I can debug this and find out what exactly is causing it? I also tried to run it on one of my University's desktops and it had the same issues as the laptop, assuming they are also running integrated graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting Directx11? Make sure you laptop supports it by running dxdiag. 
[image]

Comment: dxdiag shows 11.0 under the feature level. It also says there's no problems found.